# SQL "and/or" - which order?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I've got 2 variables which I am trying to pass in a where clause.

```
where (DeptValue = @DeptValue and AccValue = @AccValue) or (DeptValue = @DeptValue )
```

The above doesn't seem to work.  I'm trying to get results where if i just pass @Deptvalue then all Dept with any Acct records return.  But if @DeptValue and @AcctValue present, then only Dept with Acct should be returned.

Any help appreciated.  Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check the DeptValue first and then check AccValue if exists.

```
  where (DeptValue = @DeptValue) and (@AccValue is null or AccValue = @AccValue)
```

Comment: An alternative syntax to the second clause is `and (AccValue = COALESCE(@AccValue, AccValue))`

Comment: Thanks!  This only worked when I changed the order of the AccValue around.  Why is that?

Comment: @Kay_e_n It is not the order that matters. It is DeptValue has to be matched first then compare the AccValue if there is one.

Answer (score 0):

[Operator precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/operator-precedence-transact-sql):

```
Level   Operators
1       ~ (Bitwise NOT)
2       * (Multiply), / (Division), % (Modulo)
3       + (Positive), - (Negative), + (Add), (+ Concatenate), - (Subtract), & (Bitwise AND), ^ (Bitwise Exclusive OR), | (Bitwise OR)
4       =, >, <, >=, <=, <>, !=, !>, !< (Comparison operators)
5       NOT
6       AND
7       ALL, ANY, BETWEEN, IN, LIKE, OR, SOME
8       = (Assignment)
```

However, it's usually considered best practice to use parentheses to express the order operations rather than relying on precedence.